# Symfony - Angular routing

Tags: angularjs, symfony, routes, server, client

I have a symfony application which works in a subdirectory:

```
www.example.com/subdirectory
```

At this point my application is routed client side with angularjs-framework:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            redirectTo: '/homepage'
        }).
        when('/homepage', {
            templateUrl: 'index1.html',
            controller: 'HomepageCtrl'
        }).
        when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'index2.html',
            controller: 'ContactCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/homepage'
        });
}]);
```

When the site is loaded:

```
www.example.com/subdirectory
```

it automatically changes to:

```
www.example.com/subdirectory#/homepage
```

But it should be

```
www.example.com/subdirectory/#homepage
```

Anybody could help me to get this working?

Thanks and greetings!

Comment: your understanding is incorrect ... angular uses `#/path` convention. What you are seeing is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For changing the base URL of your application you could use `<base href="/subdirectory/">` inside your head tag of page.

But as per your `$routeProvider` setting the remaining part of URL seems OK to me. If you really wanted to change it then you need to replace

```
/homepage
```

with

```
homepage
```

in config phase of angular.

Comment: ok but when i call "<a href="/categories">" it automatically changes the whole url to "www.example.com/categories"

Comment: @Creativecrypter that will get fixed if you add `<base href="/subdirectory/">` as I suggested in answer